# Attempting to create Automated Email Form with Visual Studio and PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am building a website that has a form that when the submit button is selected it is supposed to send an automated email. I have been able to get the HTML portion of the form to send properly. The verification also works. The issue is no physical email is being sent. How should I error test this?

The form is built in Visual Studio using html. Here is the code for the form

```
    <div class="one_half">


            <form action="demo-contact.php method="post" id="sky-form" class="sky-form">
              <h2 class="uppercase"><strong>Contact Form</strong></h2>
              <fieldset>
                <div class="row">
                  <section class="col col-6">
                    <label class="label">Name</label>
                    <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append icon-user"></i>
                      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                    </label>
                  </section>
                  <section class="col col-6">
                    <label class="label">E-mail</label>
                    <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append icon-envelope-alt"></i>
                      <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                    </label>
                  </section>
                </div>
                <section>
                  <label class="label">Subject</label>
                  <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append icon-tag"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
                  </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                  <label class="label">Message</label>
                  <label class="textarea"> <i class="icon-append icon-comment"></i>
                    <textarea rows="4" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                  </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                  <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="copy" id="copy">
                    <i></i>Send a copy to my e-mail address</label>
                </section>
              </fieldset>
              <footer>
                <button type="submit" class="button">Send message</button>
              </footer>
              <div class="message"> <i class="icon-ok"></i>
                <p>Your message was successfully sent!</p>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>




Additonally there is a error check in


$(function()


{
            // Validation
            $("#sky-form").validate(
            {                   
                // Rules for form validation
                rules:
                {
                    name:
                    {
                        required: true
                    },
                    email:
                    {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    message:
                    {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 10
                    }
                },

                // Messages for form validation
                messages:
                {
                    name:
                    {
                        required: 'Please enter your name',
                    },
                    email:
                    {
                        required: 'Please enter your email address',
                        email: 'Please enter a VALID email address'
                    },
                    message:
                    {
                        required: 'Please enter your message'
                    }
                },

                // Ajax form submition                  
                submitHandler: function(form)
                {
                    $(form).ajaxSubmit(
                    {
                        success: function()
                        {
                            $("#sky-form").addClass('submited');
                        }
                    });
                },

                // Do not change code below
                errorPlacement: function(error, element)
                {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                }
            });
        });         

The issue I am experiencing is with the php code.


     <?php
    if( isset($_POST['name']) )
    {
        $from = "Sender <postmaster@skyvantagemedia.com>";  



        $to = "Recipient <skyvantage@outlook.com>"; 
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'] . "\n\n" . 'Regards, ' . $_POST['name'] . '.'; 
        $host = "mail.skyvantagemedia.com"; 


        //IMPORtANT: This email MUST be same as your FROM address.
        $username = "postmaster@skyvantagemedia.com";  //IMPORtANT: This email MUST be same as your FROM address.
        //IMPORtANT: This email MUST be same as your FROM address.


        $password = "*********"; 

       $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
       'To' => $to, 
       'Subject' => $subject); 
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', 
       array ('host' => $host, 
       'auth' => true, 
       'username' => $username, 
       'password' => $password)); 
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
        {
            mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
    }
?>
```

Currently the HTML works but no email is being sent. Any advice on how to error trap the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the random `4` doing after `$subject`? Btw if you're doing this on your local machine, have you got the mailsender installed/setup?

Comment: Yes, I am hosting this through mywindowshosting. The email domain skyvantagemedia is set up. the webserver is using smtp to communicate to the email server.

Comment: If it helps anyone the website is live at http://www.skyvantagemedia.com/contact.html You can enter the form but I wont receive an email...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will help or work, but here is the default/original PHP that comes with SkyPro.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( isset($_POST['name']) && strtoupper($_POST['captcha']) == $_SESSION['captcha_id'] )
    {
        $to = 'example@someEmail.com'; // Replace with your email   
        $subject = 'Message from website'; // Replace with your $subject
        $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'];    

        $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
                   'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
                   'Subject: ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n" .
                   'Message: ' . $_POST['message'];

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    
        if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
        {
            mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
    }
        ?>
```

Maybe try replacing yours with back to the original and give it a shot. Cheers!